# One photograph or two?

Tags: portrait, history, fine-art, duplicates, image-analysis

There are two prints of the same subject (Lorina Liddell by Lewis Carroll), but I'm not sure if I'm seeing two different prints of the very same negative or they are two similar, but distinct shots of the same subject.

To help you examine the situation, I made a little comparison website. Just hover/tap on the coloured buttons and observe the differences:

https://html.house/gv640544.html

Please explain any differences/similarities you see in the two images, possbly including these questions:

- are the two prints originate from the same negative?
- is she standing or sitting in the small oval picture?
- is the visible amount and quality of the sandstone wall in the background enough to determine that they show exactly the same surface and the relative position of Lorina to it?

Image sources:

- First: from Princeton University Library, Lewis Carroll Album I (sorry, I can only post 2 links)
- Second: http://www.artnet.com/artists/lewis-charles-lutwidge-dodgson-carroll/ina-liddell-playing-a-ukulele-0SvGGCYcQzXZL6OhCaFRw2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are obviously two different photographs. The position of her right hand differs significantly between the two pictures.

Comment: I agree. I think they would probably have been taken on the same day in the same location, hence the similarity in clothing and background, but I have no doubt that they are two different photos.

Comment: I agree. You have 2 different pictures, coming from 2 different negatives. In the small one, it seems the girl is sitting.